# Why can I only choose 1 IP instead of using 2 at the same time?

Tags: 14.04, server, ip

I've setted up multiple virtual IP's , but I can only choose either eth0, eth0:1 or eth0:2 . It wont use all IP's at the same time, so I can access my server only with the IP active at this moment.

this is my network/interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#iface eth0 inet dhcp


iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.46
network 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
brodcast 192.168.1.255


iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.1.41
network 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
brodcast 192.168.1.255

iface eth0:2 inet static
address 192.168.1.47
network 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
brodcast 192.168.1.255
```

Attached is a picture, which might explain my problem better (yes I have a gui on my server)

[network info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8TOv.png)

Comment: Do you have more than one NIC?

Comment: yes, but the 2nd is currently not in use

Comment: Have you tried configuring the IPs manually, with ifconfig: ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.XXX netmask 255.255.255.0  ? Are all your IPs in the same subnet?

Comment: that worked! but I previously didnt make it this way because I thougt this is not permanent? and yes they are all in the same subnet @JulenLarrucea

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following scenario:

*You have a working computer that has any os installed.

*Two network adapters are connected to the same physical network or hub.

*TCP/IP is installed as the network protocol.

*The adapter addresses on the same subnet are 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2.

*A client on the network uses the address 192.168.0.119.

In this scenario, you may expect the two adapters on the same physical network and protocol subnet to perform load balancing. However, by definition, only one adapter may communicate on the network at a time in the Ethernet network topology. Therefore, both adapters cannot be transmitting at the same time and must wait if another device on the network is transmitting. Additionally, broadcast messages must be handled by each adapter because both are listening on the same network. This configuration requires significant overhead, excluding any protocol-related issues. This configuration does not offer a good method for providing a redundant network adapter for the same network.

***the pc will only use one nic to connect to the internet***

**BUT** you can always load balance there are lots of ways to do that using fancy stuff with routing protocols or do some cool stuff within linux.

```
sudo apt-get install ifenslave
```

then edit the /etc/network/interfaces file

like this

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address 192.168.0.13
gateway 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
bond-mode balance-alb
bond-miimon 100

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0
```

and that's about it now your traffic will be load balanced through two interfaces

Comment: hello there thank you a lot taking the time: but I only use one NIC, I just use eth0 and create new virtual IP's with eth0:1 ,eth0:2 , the eth1 is not in use

Comment: same concept as i explained above .Just interface bonding wont work in this scenario,i was just explaining load balancing is possible using two interfaces using just Linux tools

Comment: so that means, hosting 2 Websties on 1 Server *at the same time*  is impossible right? But for what then is the use of adding virtual IP's?

Comment: no no sorry i wasn't clear enough with virtual interfaces you can run  server with two ip address but can access internet only with one at a time from the machine with the interfaces reside on like with apache you can run on two ips a client can connect to either one